# Return a specific number of digits

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to return a specific number of characters on a field. Basically I need 20 total characters.

So if a field returns '123'

I want it to be "123  insert 17 spaces               "

The field is not always three characters - sometimes its more or less

It doesnt seem to work.  I have one return where my field is 10 digits and that is fine, but when i retrieve the field that is 11 digits the code isnt putting in 9 spaces, it puts in 10 - I need a total of 20 characters. What i have commented out Is all returning the same results.

```
    concat(
right(replace(oe_hdr.po_no, '-', ''),8),
right(concat('000',job_price_line.line_no),3),
format(oe_pick_ticket_detail.unit_quantity, '00000000'),
--left(job_price_line.customer_part_no + '                    ',20),
--job_price_line.customer_part_no, '          ',
cast(job_price_line.customer_part_no as char(20)),
oe_pick_ticket.invoice_no)  as [po/line/release/qty/cust part no as 20 characters / invoice]
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/N98Fh.jpg

```
3013035401300000001F6740000008         1211455
80190473005000004000420232800          1209306
```

EDIT_ I guess it is working.  For some reason sql server management studio shows them out of line (see imgur) but when i export into csv its fine..... sorry.

Comment: cast to char(20)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `CAST` the data to fixed length datatype `CHAR`

```
Select Cast('123' as CHAR(20))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach might be the following:

```
SELECT LEFT('123' + '                    ', 20)
```